# Laravel project without frontend

Tags: php, laravel

currently I have a standard Laravel 5 proyect, eg:

```
 Laravel Directory
     app Directory
     bootstrap Directory
     config Directory
     database Directory
     public Directory
     resources Directory
     routes Directory
     storage Directory
     tests Directory
     vendor Directory
```

what I'm trying to do is to take the public and resources folder out from the application and put it them on a different project, and in that way I'll use the laravel part only for backend purposes and the frontend parte I'll manage it on an outside project. e.g.:

```
 Laravel Directory
     app Directory
     bootstrap Directory
     config Directory
     database Directory
     routes Directory
     storage Directory
     tests Directory
     vendor Directory

Frontend project
     index.html
     app folder
     css folder
     assets
```

Any recomendation or ideas to do it ?

Comment: So many question to myself. Want to ask you a few things. Backend meaning you want to use only console application or you want to create api from laravel? Suggestion, if you don't want to use view file, you no need to take out. Just leave it.

Comment: I want to create api from laravel to be consumed from another project apart, but I haven't found a solution for what I want, maybe its just not possible, but I think the "Just leave it" would it be the best option foe now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Removing (or moving) the Public folder is not a good idea, especially due to the fact that the `public/index.php` file is the entrypoint for the application.
I personally use both laravel and lumen for a bunch of my REST-API's and it works great, so that thought is not at all wrong.
Just ignore the views, don't use them and don't expose them from any controller action, but rather return all data from the controllers as `JSON` instead.

This is easily done from the controller actions like:

```
public function getSomethingAction() {
    return response()->json([
        "some" => "property"
    ]);
}
// Which will produce the following json (including headers and all):
{
    "some": "property"
}
```

I would also recommend that you `group` your routes under a API namespace of some sort:

```
Route::group(["prefix" => "api/v1"], function() {
    Route::get('something'...
});
```

So now when you call `domain.tdl/api/v1/something` you will get a neat json response!

Comment: this is just the answer that I was looking for!